# {'message': 'Nonce too low', 'code': -32000} when sending transaction on geth JSON-RPC

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, nonce

I am trying to send a transaction using Go Ethereum 1.4.18-stable JSON-RPC and I am getting the following error:

```
     {'message': 'Nonce too low', 'code': -32000}
```

This is a single transaction on dedicated node on Ethereum testnet. My question is that what could be the cause for this issue

- Have internal file structures of node damaged (it has lost track of nonce
- Is node simply out of sync

Answer (score 2):

Got the same issue, fixed it by indicating nonce in a transaction:

```
let nonce = web3js.eth.getTransactionCount(myAddress);
let transactionObject = {
        ...
        nonce: web3js.utils.toHex(nonce)
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Today I had the same error on Coinomi wallet. The solution was to tap .../resyncronize inside of the Eth wallet.

Answer (score 0):

I pretty sue it might network issue. i tried run `npx hardhat run --network goerli ./scripts/deploy.js` and remix https://remix.ethereum.org/ , same error appeared

Comment: Note that this question is from 2016. Hardhat did not exist for couple of years, so your error is likely a different one.

Comment: Sorry Sir you perhaps right